# Twitter Bootstrap carousel - can't change side arrows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Twitter bootstrap carousel working pretty well on my web page, but I can't get the side arrows to behave the way I want. My CSS knowledge is maybe a 5 out of 10.

Currently the "glyph" arrows are absolute positioned from the left and right edges of the window. As I shrink or grow the window, those arrows stay exactly the same distance from the window edges. Which is weird and wrong because they move all over the place on top of the carousel images. I want them to stay in fixed position on the carousel image, not on the browser window. Also I need to change the font glyphs to transparent images.

The arrows on the left and right scroll the carousel when clicked. They are not images, they're glyphs, which I guess is some kind of weird font. Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev" style="width:0px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" style="width:0px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

Here is the css for the href:

```
.carousel-control {
background: #343432;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 15%;
font-size: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

And here is the css for the inner span:

```
.glyphicon-chevron-right {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
z-index: 5;
display: inline-block;
}
```

And:

```
.glyphicon {
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Though it doesn't show in the raw html, when looking through Chrome dev toolbar inspector, inside the span I see this:

```
::before
```

So I need to know how to change the arrow positions to stay fixed relative to the carousel images, not the browser window. And I need to change the glyphs to some transparent arrows that I have.

Here is the actual web page in case you want to inspect any elements:
http://www.zerogravpro.com/temp/bootstrap/

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have made a copy of your code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Cwf/embedded/result/) to recreate the problem.

You have an structure like this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
   <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control"></a>
   <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control"></a>
</div>
```

Where the `a` tags are the navigation arrows and are positioned `absolute` in relation to his container `#myCarousel`. The actual position of the spans inside makes the arrow away from the edge.

Since the container `#myCarousel` is always resized with the screen then the arrows are always visible and can be at the limits with this:

- First remove the style inline for the `a` tags:

  ```
  <a href="#myCarousel" class="left" ... /*style="width:0px" Remove this*/>
  ```
- Then Add this on your CSS:

  ```
  .carousel-control {
    top:50%;
    width:auto;
    height:1em;
    background:transparent;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right  {
    position:static;
    display:block;
    width:auto;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left:before {
    margin-left:0;
  }
  ```

And Now you Have **[THIS RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Cwf/2/)**

Now to change the *arrow* to an image you can reset the content of the `before` pseudo-element and instead add your image as a background like this:

```
   .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right:before {
       //Reset the icon
       content: " ";
       //Give layout
       display:block;
       //Your image as background
       background:url('http://yourarrow.png') no-repeat;
       //To show full image set the dimensions
       width:30px;
       height:30px;
   }
```

And Now you can Have **[THIS RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Cwf/3/)**

Comment: Danko, this looks very promising, but in jsfiddle it still shows the right/left arrow aligned to the sides of the window, rather than aligned on the left and right sides of the image. How can the arrows be position on top of the image, on the left and right side? If you drag that jsfiddle window wider, you'll see that the arrows stick with the window, not the image.

Comment: @SweatCoder as I said in the answer the position of the arrows is attached to the container that grows up and down with the window givin the same effect. Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d4Cwf/6/embedded/result/)

Comment: @SweatCoder Or like this another option http://jsfiddle.net/d4Cwf/7/embedded/result/ but you will need to change strcuture and JS

Comment: Danko, you saved me. This fiddle was closest, though I had to mod it a fair amount: http://jsfiddle.net/d4Cwf/6/embedded/result/. Anyway you got me out of the woods. Enjoy the points.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go Sweat Coder. I recreated the code. I saw that you are using `class="container"` multiple times. and for the carousel to work properly you must include the controls inside the `class="container`. I replaced the `<span>` tags with `<img>` in the controls for the custom images.

Feel free to comment if you have any questions.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GcY3V/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper" style=";margin-top:0px">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://www.zerogravpro.com/temp/bootstrap/images/1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.zerogravpro.com/temp/bootstrap/images/2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://www.zerogravpro.com/temp/bootstrap/images/3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <img class="chevron chevron-left" src="http://alexoliveira.me/Hawaii/images/chevron-left.png" />
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <img class="chevron chevron-right" src="http://alexoliveira.me/Hawaii/images/chevron-right.png" />
   </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chevron {
    width:30%;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
}
.container {
    background-color:#343432;
}
.chevron-left {
    left:5%;
}
.chevron-right {
    right:5%;
}
body {
    background-color:#343432
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to load jQuery. I updated the Fiddle though the question was already answered.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me. I just added the CSS to the carousel css file and placed the images in the right folder, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"><img src="images/left_arrow.png" class="img-responsive"></span>
</a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"><img src="images/right_arrow.png" class="img-responsive"></span>
</a>
```

css

```
 .glyphicon-chevron-left,
 .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
   z-index: 5;
   display: inline-block;
   }
```

Comment: Atal: I tried your solution but it didn't work. My image icons appeared, but they didn't float over my carousel image. Instead they floated off past the left side and ride side. Also they weren't clickable, and the glyphs remained. The old glyphs became non-clickable also (no image movement when clicked). Is there something else I could try?

Comment: when i was using this code i have removed the glphs from bootstrap.css  & there is no need to add glyphs anymore here.It is 100% working for me.

Comment: Atal: Can you put a link to your css file or something? It doesn't work for me and I have no idea what changes you have made. I tried your posted code and it did nothing; in fact it made it worse. I would love to get your solution.

Comment: check the live code [here](http://cmchistn.com/REMEDINET/index.html) which i have created

Comment: Looks great, but that seems to be a full website with a carousel behaving almost the way I want. There are important differences. I'm not sure how I can use this.

Comment: i'll create the bootstrap carousel once again for you on monday and posted the code. its easy to change css and js of carousel according to our need. thats the unused version of my company website where i have used bootstrap but i realised 960 gs is much more better if you are looking to grid system

Comment: Remove the glyphicon classes from the spans. That will remove the original glyphs. That should help with the placement of the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the whole `.carousel` class in a `.container` div it should keep the carousel controls with the image and not the website itself. However, I disabled the responsiveness with my site, so this may not be exactly what you're looking for.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
            <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control"></a>
            <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control"></a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view a lot of stuffs on this link http://www.landcoder.com/codes-change-style-carousel-bootstrap-367 in terms of modifying the sourcecode of bootstrap carousel.

I think your problem is the problem:

```
 .carousel-control {
   background: #343432;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; /* this might be your problem */
  }
```

If you want to side arrows move according to the image, change top to 50%.

```
   .carousel-control {
     background: #343432;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
  }
```